# Graphics Card that allows to emulate 4 FullHD Windows Screens on a single 4k Display

Tags: graphics-cards, 4k

I´m currently facing a situation where i want to Display
4 Windows Screens on a single 80" 4k Display for demonstration purposes.

The ideal solution would be a single graphics card that allows to attach a 4k Display (using Displayport or HDMI 2.0) and emulate 4 FullHD (1080p) Displays to Windows?

Normally, the application is spread accross 4 Windows Monitors(each is 1080p). For Demos i want to display the 4 FullHD Windows Monitors on a single 4k Multitouch 80" Screen stitched together. 
I know that there are boxes out there that have 4 Inputs and deliver a single 4k output. I just wonder if there is a GraphicsCard (with drivers) only solution for such a setup.

If there is an AMD/ATI-based solution available, that would be even better (as the application that should be demonstrated is optimized towards AMDs drivers)
Any recommendations?

Comment: 4 different *instances* of windows? 4 different windows desktops spread out? 4 applications? You can pretty trivially do the last in software on any windows system. The others get trickier

Comment: We need to know what your displaying.  Almost any semi-modern card can power 4k if it is display webpages, videos, or other pre-rendered content.  However, 4 3D video games on a 4k display would take 2 cards to get decent frame rates.